# How to build my own Ext JS 3.3.1?

Tags: extjs

I want to know how to build my own Ext JS with only the js files I need, or if there is a feature in Ext JS where I can just load the individual components that I need.  Ext JS is a lot of the size of my application, and it is not working without including ext-all.js.

Comment: I'd rather try to compress the js file :) (remove indentation and compress with gzip)

Comment: Iam using minified version.After compressing with gzip .how should i include Is giving me error "Illegal Character" .I have included in the foll manner : <script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js.gz"></script>

Comment: check this out: http://www.thewebdevelopmentblog.com/2008/10/tip-speed-up-your-websites-using-gzip-and-merging-files/ (I assumed you are using php.. )

Comment: so? did it work when you compressed and served via php?

Comment: Catalin,KEEP IT IP. I hv implemented it & its performance is gd as i found in YSlow. Now point is while theaap is running it is taken care off but I want reduce physical size too as we are building a plugin for which we are using ext js & user would find the size is too high for downloading

Comment: Btw, if you don't use extjs components like panels, windows and friends :) have you considered using jquery or prototype?

Comment: no I havent used jquery or prototype

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sollution:

Use a php script to serve compressed css or js scripts like in the example in the link below:

http://www.thewebdevelopmentblog.com/2008/10/tip-speed-up-your-websites-using-gzip-and-merging-files/